# MapStruct: Is it possible to specify using the same named mapping for all nested fields of a type?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is it possible to specify the qualifier for a nested mapper without having to specify it for *each* instance of a particular type of bean?

Some code to illustrate my point. I have a Parent object like:

```java
public class ParentDTO {
    ChildDTO childA;
    ChildDTO childB;
    ChildDTO childC;
   // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

and I have a ChildMapper that includes more than one mapping:

```java
@Mapper
public interface ChildMapper {
    @Named("MinimalChildMapper")
    @Mapping(target = "someAttribute", ignore = true)
    ChildDTO toMinimalChildDTO(Child child);

    @Named("ChildMapper")
    ChildDTO toChildDTO(Child child);
}
```

I know that I can specify which child mapper to use *for each child* like this:

```java
@Mapper(uses = ChildMapper.class)
public interface ParentMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "childA", qualifiedByName = "MinimalChildMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "childB", qualifiedByName = "MinimalChildMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "childC", qualifiedByName = "MinimalChildMapping")
    ParentDTO toParentDTO(Parent parent);
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is some way to use the mapping indicated in each qualifiedByName for the *type* (ChildDTO) rather that having to specify it for each *instance* of the type (childA, childB, childC). Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you need a qualifier? When using no qualifier you get exactly what you need, the same 'toChildDto method reused (called). In general: you only use qualifiers when you want to resolve a conflict when mapstuct sees methods with the same signature and it cannot decide which one to use. You then write qualifiers for the'special' cases leaving the majority to the method without a qualifier (default). Looking from that perspective, the scenario you sketch strikes me as odd

Comment: @Sjaak, I'm using the qualifier for the reason you outline-- because in my ChildMapper I have two signatures that have the same arguments and same return type and needed to instruct when importing into the ParentMapper which to use. The qualifier I'm asking about fits the "special" case you describe. I don't really need a name on the `toChildDTO` method signature, but that's not the one I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.

However, what you could do is to have 2 `ChildMapper`(s). That way you can use the one with the minimal in your `ParentMapper`. One other option would be to defined the minimal mapping in your `ParentMapper` instead of reusing the `ChildMapper`.